# What is Generalization? Why is it important?

Tags: matrices

In my Natural Language Processing class, we just talked about the Generalization of a Jacobian Matrix. So far I’ve been understanding the material, okay, but now I’m very confused.

I came across these slides [Natural Language Processing with Deep Learning CS224N/Ling284](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/slides/cs224n-2020-lecture04-neuralnets.pdf), in the context of natural language processing, which talks about the Jacobian as a generalization of the gradient.

I'm not clear on when and why to perform a Generalization?

I know there is a lot of topic regarding this on the internet, and trust me, I've googled it. I got answers to generalizing the [matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672239/generalization-of-gradient-using-jacobian-hessian-wronskian-and-laplacian) and distributions but no proper explanation on "Generalization" and why it is so important?

Comment: What is the definition of the generalization that you were given? One way of defining a matrix is as an indexing function with indexing set $[m]\times [n]$ where $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ is a section of the positive integers. You can generalize this to an arbitrary finite Cartesian product of sections of the positive integers. There are certainly applications of such a structure since you might want to iterate through some object of that many dimensions.

Comment: "Generalization" is an **extremely** broad term. You should give more details about exactly *what kind of* generalization you are asking about, otherwise it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155576) somehow relevant? @Pluviophile

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Not completely

Comment: @LeeMosher the reference that is linked by the author narrows the notion of generalization. I think it pertains to how Jacobian is generalization of gradient in multi-dimension. Please do care to check the reference and provide your input as this is quite interesting point.